# Función getEmails para pasarlos a Google Sheet, quiero que me extraiga solamente los no leídos

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, gmail

Quiero consultarles si me pueden ayudar a encontrar un error que anteriormente no me ocurría con el mismo script.

Cada vez q se ejecuta, cuando se da el caso que haya algún mail que cumpla con las condiciones, como que este No Leído, me trae otra vez mails anteriores que están leídos. Para esto desactive la opción de google de agrupar los mails de conversaciones para efectivamente ver que están Leídos.

Los mails llegan de formularios, y son casi iguales todos.

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = 'label:Inbox is:unread from:cotizar@todo.com.ar     subject:Formulario ';

// Credit: https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/70e04a67f1f5fd96a708

function getEmails_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g,' ','/')
            ]);
        }
}
return emails;
}
function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length,     array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}
function run(){
  var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
  if (array2d) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1c52lPT8oEu-lPloYu_n-    apCWiTQgeYP7Wz9cdK2I3w");
    Logger.log(ss.getName());
    var sheet =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Potenciales');
    if (sheet != null) {
    Logger.log(sheet.getIndex());
        appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
    }
  markArchivedAsRead ();
    }
    function markArchivedAsRead() {
      var threads = GmailApp.search('label:Inbox is:unread         from:cotizar@todo.com.ar subject:Formulario ');
      GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
  }
 }
```

Comment: A mi me funciona bien, al menos la parte de obtención de los no leídos. ¿Probaste el valor final de `emails` en `getEmails_`?  ¿En realidad crea un array con elementos no deseados?¿El problema no será aquí: `sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length,     array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);`? ¿Aquí que intentas hacer: `emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g,' ','/')]`? quizá podrías usar `.getPlainBody()` simplemente...

Comment: Hola, funciona bien, pero siempre obtengo toda la conversacion (Mismo Dia; Remitente;Asunto).

Comment: Es que no sé lo que quieres decir con que obtienes toda la conversación. ¿No será entonces alguna configuración en tu GMail? ¿Podrías simplificar obteniendo algo como el id del mensaje y mostrar un ejemplo de los resultados que obtienes en la variable `emails`?  Si obtienes el id verás si realmente obtienes duplicados o no, pues cada id es distinto.

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que si hay 9 mails el mismo del mismo remitente y hay 8 leidos y uno no, obtengo los 9 mails. y Cada vez que llega uno nuevo lo mismo. El nuevo y los anteriores.

Comment: La configuración de Gmail "Vista de conversación:
(Establece si los correos electrónicos sobre el mismo tema deben agruparse)" Puede habilitarse o no. Yo la inhabilite y veo los correos uno por uno. Si estas probando, proba teniendo 3 o 4 mails del mismo remitente y solo uno no leído, a ver si te obtiene ese o todos. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La cuestión es que el parámetro `is:unread` parece no servir de nada aquí... Pues luego, al leer los mensajes del hilo, te los trae todos (los leídos y los no leídos), por lo que hay que preguntar por cada mensaje usando `isUnread()`, metiéndolos en el array cuando esa condición se cumpla.

No sé si hay alguna forma de mejorar la query para que efectivamente incluya en este caso los mensajes no leídos únicamente.

El código funciona de esta manera:

```
function getEmails_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    var messages = threads[0].getMessages(); 

    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        /*Solamente si es no leído lo incluimos en el array*/
        if(messages[i].isUnread()){
          emails.push([messages[i].getSubject()]);
        }  
    }
    return emails;
}
```

En este caso he obtenido solamente el asunto del email por motivos de simplicidad.

La prueba se hizo sobre estos mensajes que tienen todos el mismo contenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, hay solamente tres mensajes no leídos. Yo escribí el resultado del array en una hoja de prueba, y helo aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

<s>Debo decir que, si quito el parámetro `is:unread` de los criterios de búsqueda, el código funciona exactamente igual.</s>  Me retracto de esto, dado que si omito ese parámetro, aunque el resultado final es el mismo, me trae todos los hilos.

Comment: Gracias, Funcionó así ,                                                                               
  for (var i in threads) {
        /*Solamente si es no leído lo incluimos en el array*/
        if(messages[i].isUnread()){
          emails.push([messages[i].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g,' ','/')]);                        Gracias

Comment: Me alegro de que haya funcionado @Hernan527 . Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda. Y considera usar `getPlainBody()` en lugar de esto: `getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g,' ','/')`.

Comment: con getPlainBody(), me trae Mensaje de Prueba, que es algo que està en el archivo SendEmail.php del PHPMailer. Correspondería otro hilo. Gracias